# Position of subscript associated with summation symbol

Tags: equations, symbols, subscripts

To conserve space, I wish to generate

```
$\sum_{i \in B}$
```

[image]

However, when I put the Latex code into \begin{equation}, using

```
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i \in B}
\end{equation}
```

it becomes
[image]

No. Just no.

Can someone please help to make the subscript more like the top one. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `\sum\nolimits_{i\in B}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `amsmath` with the `nosumlimits` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nosumlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{a\in A}\prod_{b\in B}
\bigcap_{c\in C}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]